# "non-www to www" and "https" rewrite rule in web.config but not localhost ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following rewrite rule in the `web.config` of my ASP.NET MVC 5 project:

```
<rule name="Redirect example.com to www.example.com and enforce https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The rule redirects non-www to www and http to https (so something like `http://example.com/hey` will redirect to `https://www.example.com/hey`) and works fine. It however also works on `localhost`, and I can't seem to be able to work around it — I've tried negation rules and regular expressions containing `|` but can't seem to be able to find the correct combinations. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `conditions` block you can use attribute `negate="true"`. If this attribute is set and condition is matched, then rewrite rule is not applied.

The description of `negate` attribute from [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference):

> A pattern can be negated by using the negate attribute of the 
>   element. When this attribute is used, the rule action is performed
>   only if the current URL does not match the specified pattern.

Since you are using `MatchAny`, adding additional attribute will not match, because at least one of the conditions will be met anyway. I recommend using 2 specific rewrite rules with `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"`, where each one is responsible just for single case:

```
<rule name="enforce https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" 
              pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
          appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect example.com to www.example.com"
       enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" 
              pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}"
         appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this in Chrome on the live site: "www.example.com redirected you too many times. `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`" - same in Firefox

Comment: @globetrotter I think it was issue with `MatchAny` - see if updated answer with `MatchAll` helps

Comment: now it works for the live site but tries to add `https` on `localhost`

Comment: Are you using port other than 80 on localhost?

Comment: @globetrotter I updated the answer to also support port on localhost